# var so = {name: 'stack'}['overflow'];

Tags: javascript

```
var so = {name: 'stack'}['overflow'];
undefined
```

What is this expression exactly doing? Neither the console produces any errors nor `so` contains any data.

**UPDATE**

1. If I directly type `{name: 'stack'}['overflow']` in console it prints `["overflow"]`
2. While `{name: 'stack', location: 'somewhere'}['overflow']` gives error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :(…)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`{name: 'stack'}` is called an Object literal, which has a property called `name` and its corresponding value is `stack`.

`{name: 'stack'}['overflow']` is trying to get the value for the property `overflow` from the object literal.

Since the property is not there in the object, by default, `undefined` is returned and that is stored in the variable `so`.

---

In the Console,

1. `{name: 'stack'}` is being treated as a block and `name:` is considered as the [label statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). Since there is nothing happening inside that block, it simply returns `['overflow']` as it is.

   If you want that to be evaluated as a single expression, then you need to wrap that in parenthesis, like this

   ```
   ({name: 'stack'}['overflow'])
   // undefined
   ```
2. In the second case, it sees a label in the block, `name:`, and then it sees `'stack', location: 'somewhere'`, which is not parsable by the JavaScript engine. That is why you are getting the error. Same way, wrap the expression in parenthesis to get the actual value, like this

   ```
   ({name: 'stack', location: 'somewhere'}['overflow'])
   // undefined
   ```

Comment: Does this mean that 'name' is not considered as a label when used inside parenthesis?

Comment: @Shreyas Yes, when you use that inside parenthesis, it is considered as Object literal;

Answer (score 3):

It'll set `so` (not `foo` - there's no mention of that) to `undefined`.

In more detail, the expression `{name: 'stack'}` is an "object literal" that creates a JS object with a single key (`name`) with value `stack`.

The `['overflow']` then tries to extract the given key from that object, but it doesn't contain that key, so that evaluates to `undefined`.

Putting it altogether: `var so = undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

In ideal scenario code should have been

`var so = {name: 'stack'};
console.log(so.overflow);` // output is `undefined` as there is no `overflow` property on object `so`

There is another way you can access property of an object using `[]`,

`console.log(so['overflow']);`

Now if you combine everything in one statement

`var so = {name: 'stack'}['overflow'];` //obviously `undefined`

Point to notice is, if you just have `{name: 'stack'}['overflow'];` it should give error, weird thing is both Firefox and Chrome does something following:

> ```
> {a:'aa'}['bbbb'];
> ["bbbb"] //printed output  
>
> {a:'aa',b:'bb'}['bbbb'];
> VM529:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :(…)
> ```

---

> If anyone can explain why?

---

Answer (score 0):

You make a new object with only a field name, then it tries to retrieve the field overflow. You can test this by doing this instead:

```
iets={name:"stack overflow"}["name"]
```

The other reason it gives undefined is : the console always gives undefined if you put var in front of it.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is "different" in some ways, so lets break it down into 2 steps.

```
var so = {name: 'stack'};
```

This creates a new object called `so`, with a property `name`.

```
so['overflow']
```

In javascript you can read a property from an object using the array brackets, so this code tries to read the `overflow` property from the `so` object.
Since you don't have have, it's value is `undefined`.

When you put it all together, you are creating a new object and then trying to a read a non-existent property from it, which will result in the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

**There is not an answer. This is my personal advice**

Why don't you try this for seeing with your own eyes what is happening:

```
var foo = {name : "stack"}["overflow"];
var bar = {name : "stack", overflow : "foobar" }["overflow"];
console.log(foo);
console.log(bar);
```